# How to create loading screen while app is loading with Tkinter

Tags: python, multithreading, object, tkinter

I have the next problem. I'm new with this multi-threading thing. I made a program to transform pdf to docx and vice versa. The issue is that I want to put a loading screen while the conversion takes place, but I can't find a way to execute both the loading screen and the method at the same time. I discovered that I can use multithreading, but I still can't execute both methods at the same time. I have this:

```
Thread(target = Conversor()).start()
Thread(target = loading_screen()).start()
```

Conversor is an object that has an `__init__`, which opens a tkinter window. With this code, the loading screen, which is this:

```
def loading_screen():
    chars = "/—\|" 
    for char in chars:
        sys.stdout.write('\r'+'loading...'+char)
        time.sleep(.1)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Doesn't even appear. Even if it did, it would appear after I finish everything in the tkinter window.
First, I wanted to see if both methods executed at the same time, so I would then order the loading_screen method to appear when the program loads, but it doesn't even appear.

Any solution? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this

```py
from tkinter import *
import sys
from threading import Thread
import time

class Conversor(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.loaded=False
        self.geometry('400x300')
        Thread(target=self.loading_screen).start()
        label=Label(self)
        label.pack()
        for i in range(10000): #Increase load time
            label['text']+=str(i)
            if i%100==0:
                label['text']+='\n'

    def loading_screen(self):
        idx=0
        while not self.loaded:
            chars = r"/—\|" 
            sys.stdout.write('\r'+'loading...'+chars[idx])
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if idx==len(chars)-1:
                idx=0
            else:
                idx+=1
            time.sleep(.1)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write('\nloaded')

    def start(self):
        self.loaded=True
        self.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    conversor=Conversor()
    conversor.start()
```

The `loading_screen` thread has been called right after `Tk` is initialized, and the flag `self.loaded` is set to `False`. `self.loaded` becomes `True` right before the `mainloop()` begins indicating the GUI has been loaded.